# how to download angular 2 using bower?

Tags: bower, yeoman, angular

I've just started learning angular 2 and though of create a small app using it but could not find way to use angular 2 modules like angular 2,routers etc , So could some please help out in how to download and manage angular 2 modules using bower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no official bower package for angular 2. Use npm instead.

```
npm install angular2 --save
```

Comment: Funnily, running "bower install angular2" now installs angular 1.4.8